# How and when to apply business rules?

Tags: validation, business-rules

Suppose I have a service *StateService* which has a method *ChangeState*.

```
ChangeState(State toState, DomainObject object)
```

I have business rules that checks whether the destination state is valid or not in the domain objects current "state", how can I technically check those rules without first setting the toState on the domain object? It feels wrong to first **set the new state**, run validation and if one or more rule breaks **unset the state**.

One solution I came up with is to create some context object that drives the validation eg.
**ChangeStateContext** that contains the DomainObject along with the State that is to be set.

Another related question is how to report back from the ChageState call how it went?
I can collect all validation rules that broke and throw an exception with those rules that the caller can catch and handle accordingly or I can add a return type on the ChangeState-method like **ValidationSummary** that contains information about broken rules and such. What is best practices in these cases?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you throw an exception from the `ChangeState` method when the state transformation is invalid? You can throw specific exceptions such as `StateTransformationException` or `ValidationException` that you can catch higher on the call stack. You can optionally include extra properties to these exception types so that you can communicate very precisely what went wrong to the user.

When you want to call multiple ChangeStates after a single user action, you will need a way to revert or rollback. What I usually do is using the unit of work pattern (supplied to me by LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework) and change all state within this unit of work. When an exception is thrown I throw away the complete unit of work with all its changes.

Answer (score 0):

The `DomainObject` class could have a `public bool CanChangeState(State toState)` instance method, returning `True` if `toState` is a valid transition from the current state of the subject `DomainObject`. Such method can be called prior to the `StateService.ChangeState` call.

Of course, if the `StateService` is responsible for the state change validation, then a `CanChangeState(State toState, DomainObject obj)` method should be added to the `StateService`.

To report back the validation error messages, change the return Type of the `CanChangeState` to a custom Type responsible for reporting validation errors.